# subvarieties define a cycle reference

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology

What is the standard reference (book, Theorem number) for the statement that a complex subvariety of a smooth complex variety defines a homology class? I need to cite it in the thesis and I was told that it is the Griffiths-Harris book, though I do not have a copy of it to find the concrete Theorem which states this.

Comment: This should probably be flaired with reference-request

Comment: Ah sorry, is there a section for reference-requests on this website or something?